# JSX file placing stopped working

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I have a .jsx script I'm using to place a set of png files into a clipping group. Was working fine yesterday, today it fails with error code 9080:

```
Unable to set placed item's file, is the file path provided valid? Or try to use the raster item instead.
```

Nothing has changed - same set of png file, same jsx. Problem is this loop:

```
for ( i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) { 
    var name = files[i].name.slice(0, -4);    
    thisPlace = clipGroup.placedItems.add(); 
    thisPlace.file = files[i];
}
```

Error throws on the final line - thisPlace.file = files[i].

files is a valid set of files selected from a given folder. Is there any other way I could try to achieve the same?

What else could be causing the issue?

Comment: Check if the error is thrown for a specific file.

Comment: have you logged files[i] to ensure the file path is actually valid in that loop?

Comment: Yeah, so, I went for IT help 101 - turned the machine off. Turned it back on again. Works fine. Probably stems from using CS4 on win10...